# JQuery - Increment css position without removing the original position

Tags: jquery

I'm making a card game and I would like to move the cards as they arrive in hand so I increment left position but it's overwriting the original position.

Well, an image will explain better what I want to do :
[Click here :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA8kb.png)

Here is my JQuery function :

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.card').eq(next).show(function(){
        count = $('.handed').length;
        cardPos = 70 - (count*10);
        $('.card').eq(next).css('transform', 'translateY(30%) translateX(-50%)').css('left', cardPos+'%').addClass('handed');
        next++;
        $('.handed').css('left', '+='+50+'px');
    });
}, 1000);
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: I think I would probably just create css rules for this using `:nth-child()`

Comment: Can you draw a simple picture to show what you want?

Comment: P.S: instead of using `.css("p","v").css("p","v")` use `.css({p:"v", p:"v"})`

Comment: and yeah, your question is unclear. read it twice and you'll understand what I mean... Please [edit] it, do your best in explaining and if possible create a [mcve]

Comment: I just made an image, hope this is more clear now